# How to send request to the server only once by using @NgRx/effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Currently, I want to use NgRx on my project, and I have a question connected with getting data from the server.

For example, I have this code.

**in component**

```js
// import ....

export class ToDoComponent implements OnInit {
  todo$: Observable<ToDoState>;
  ToDoSubscription: Subscription;
  ToDoList: ToDo[] = [];

  constructor(private store: Store<{ todos: ToDoState }>) {
    this.todo$ = store.pipe(select('todos'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ToDoSubscription = this.todo$
      .pipe(
        map(x => {
          this.ToDoList = x.ToDos;
          this.todoError = x.ToDoError;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();

    this.store.dispatch(ToDoActions.BeginGetToDoAction());
  }
}
```

and this one

**in Effects**

```js
// import ....

@Injectable()
export class ToDoEffects {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private action$: Actions) {}

  private ApiURL: string = 'https://localhost:44308/api/ToDo';

  GetToDos$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(ToDoActions.BeginGetToDoAction),
      mergeMap(action =>
        this.http.get(this.ApiURL).pipe(
          map((data: ToDo[]) => {
            return ToDoActions.SuccessGetToDoAction({ payload: data });
          }),
          catchError((error: Error) => {
            return of(ToDoActions.ErrorToDoAction(error));
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Does it mean that I will send a request to the server every time when the user navigates to the `ToDoComponent` component?

If yes, how can I configure my effect to send a request only once?

Or what is the best way for this case?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everytime you navigate to the component it will fetch the todo.

This is because of the dispatch line,

```
this.store.dispatch(ToDoActions.BeginGetToDoAction());
```

You can check if it's already present in the store as seen in [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#4-using-a-selector-inside-your-effects)

```
@Effect()
getOrder = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<GetOrder>(ActionTypes.GetOrder),
  withLatestFrom(action =>
    of(action).pipe(
      this.store.pipe(select(getOrders))
    )
  ),
  filter(([{payload}, orders]) => !!orders[payload.orderId])
  mergeMap([{payload}] => {
    ...
  })
)
```

Or you can just put a `take(1)` in your effect:

```
  GetToDos$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(ToDoActions.BeginGetToDoAction),
      mergeMap(action =>
        this.http.get(this.ApiURL).pipe(
          map((data: ToDo[]) => {
            return ToDoActions.SuccessGetToDoAction({ payload: data });
          }),
          catchError((error: Error) => {
            return of(ToDoActions.ErrorToDoAction(error));
          })
        )
      ),
      take(1)
    )
  );
```

here is the stackblitz example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6jctm

Comment: Thank you very much @timdeschryver. I couldn't make work the first example, but the second example works as expected. let me update Your answer and put there the Stackblitz link with your second example. And thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So, The approach you can try is saving the API response in the sessionStorage and check for the availability for the response in the session storage when the user navigates to the ToDoComponent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I thought about it, but I want to know is it possible with effects or what is the right way in this case.

Comment: Ok, Can you please upload your code in stackblitz. So, that I can see your whole code.

Comment: Hi Devashish Sharma. Sorry for the delay. I have created the Stackblitz example, But my question already answered by @timdeschryver. If the answer is interested please check the Stackblitz link ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6jctm ).

Comment: Glad to know that It worked. I haven't checked the ngrx framework until now. Seems like it stores the data in localStorage and provides elegant ways to store the state data.

Comment: Hello Devanshish Sharma, no it doesn't store the data into any browser storages. just it stores the data. It helps you separate the logic of manipulations with the data in one place. The effects help you do something when working some actions. For more info please check (https://ngrx.io/guide/store) and (https://ngrx.io/guide/effects)

Comment: Oh, I see it doesn't store the data in external storage. I thought it stores it in external storage after looking through this doc https://ngrx.io/docs#serializability