# Angular NGRX: Use withLatestFrom to call api only once. However, 'loader' is still set to true

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I created the following code, trying to ensure the api is not called again when the state is set, and avoid using subscriptions in the component.

```
loadPackingList$ = createEffect(() => {
   return this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(PackingPageActions.loadPackingList),
     switchMap((action) =>
         of(action).pipe(
            withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectPackingList)),

            filter(([action, list]) => !list || list.length === 0),

            switchMap(([action, latest]) =>
               this.packingService.getPackingList(action.request).pipe(
               map((list) => PackingApiActions.loadPackingListSuccess({ list })),
               catchError((errors) =>
                   of(PackingApiActions.loadPackingListFail({ errors }))
             )
           )
         )
       )
     )
   );
});
```

This more or less works (the api is not called again) and is based amongst others on:
[How to send request to the server only once by using @NgRx/effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820656/how-to-send-request-to-the-server-only-once-by-using-ngrx-effects)

However, the loading property is still set to true again, which should not happen:

```
export const packingReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(PackingPageActions.loadPackingList, (state) => ({
   ...state,
   loading: true,
})),
```

component's OnInit:

```
this.store.dispatch(
  PackingPageActions.loadPackingList({ request: this.PACKING_REQUEST })
);
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you can clean up the stream a bit:

```
loadPackingList$ = createEffect(() => {
   return this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(PackingPageActions.loadPackingList),
     withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectPackingList)),
     filter(([action, list]) => !list || list.length === 0),
     switchMap(([action, latest]) =>
       this.packingService.getPackingList(action.request).pipe(
         map((list) => PackingApiActions.loadPackingListSuccess({ list })),
         catchError((errors) =>
           of(PackingApiActions.loadPackingListFail({ errors }))
         )
       )
     )
   );
});
```

don't need the external `switchMap` into `of`, just redundant.

second, you'll need to also put a similar check into your reducer to make sure it doesn't get set unless the effect will actually go:

```
export const packingReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(PackingPageActions.loadPackingList, (state) => ({
   ...state,
   loading: !state.whatever.the.path.to.the.list.is?.length,
})),
```

or instead of filtering, you could just mock responses with the already fetched list:

```
loadPackingList$ = createEffect(() => {
   return this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(PackingPageActions.loadPackingList),
     withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectPackingList)),
     switchMap(([action, latest]) =>
       ((latest && latest.length) ? of(latest) : this.packingService.getPackingList(action.request)).pipe(
         map((list) => PackingApiActions.loadPackingListSuccess({ list })),
         catchError((errors) =>
           of(PackingApiActions.loadPackingListFail({ errors }))
         )
       )
     )
   );
});
```

you could do this in other ways, like having another action in there that signals the request is actually going out like `loadPackingListRequest` request that the effect will emit right before the request to signal it's actually happening, and this is what sets the `loading` state to true, probably cleaner this way since you don't have a hidden dependency on synchronizing code between your reducer and effects. but it's preference at this point.

EDIT:

the third action strategy would look a bit like this:

```
loadPackingList$ = createEffect(() => {
   return this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(PackingPageActions.loadPackingList),
     withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectPackingList)),
     filter(([action, list]) => !list || list.length === 0),
     switchMap(([action, latest]) => from([
       of(PackingApiActions.loadingPackingList()),
       this.packingService.getPackingList(action.request).pipe(
         map((list) => PackingApiActions.loadPackingListSuccess({ list })),
         catchError((errors) =>
           of(PackingApiActions.loadPackingListFail({ errors }))
         )
       )
     ]).pipe(mergeAll()))
   );
});
```

this way your effect will emit two actions, one indicating it is actually doing the loading, and another indicating if it failed or succeeded.

then you modify the reducer to look at the loading action instead to set loading to true:

```
export const packingReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(PackingApiActions.loadingPackingList, (state) => ({
   ...state,
   loading: true,
})),
```

Comment: Thanks!! Is there an advantage of using mock responses vs filtering? I will look into using an extra action now as you explained

Comment: Well. Using a mocked response has a drawback that your store is Gona think something changed when it didn’t. But filtering without the third action means your code in your reducer needs to be aware of your code in your effects. Which is somewhat bad design. IMO the third action strategy is prob the best. I could post an example of what that would look like.

Comment: All right, thanks for the explanation! And yes please, I love 'best' solutions! :D

Comment: posted what third action solution would look like

Comment: Thanks! It works when I add the action as:
export const loadingPackingList = createAction(
  '[Expedition Api] Loading Packing List',
  props<{ loading: boolean }>()
);

And the of in the effect:
of(PackingApiActions.loadingPackingList({ loading: true })),

But then the 'true' should be determined somehow? But not sure if you ment it to be like this? And would I delete the initial action in the reducer?

  on(PackingPageActions.loadPackingList, (state) => ({
    ...state
    // loading: !state.list?.length

Comment: you don't need to determine the true, because the `loading` action being emited means it IS loading. yes, in this case you would remove the initial action from the reducer as it is redundant.